# Prove that the existence of a bridge is an invariant

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, invariance

An invariant is a property $P$ that is shared by all isomorphic graphs. In other words, a property $P$ is an invariant provided that whenever $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic graphs, if $G_1$ satisfies $P$, then $G_2$ also satisfies $P$.

A bridge is an edge $e$ whose removal yields a disconnected graph.

Comment: Have you tried anything? This seems to follow *immediatly* from the very *definition* of brige and isomorphic...

Comment: How do you calculate that (boolean) invariant?

Comment: @fdg That's what I am confused by, how I can prove something by using more than just definitions?

Answer (score 1):

*Illustration*:  Below I generated a random connected graph (the blue graph) and highlighted it's bridges in orange.  Then I relabeled the vertices of the graph to form the red graph below highlighted it's bridges in orange too.

[image: A graph and an isomorphic graph]

It's quite clear in the above example that bridges map to bridges and non-bridges map to non-bridges.  The graph's structure has not changed.  This is all isomorphism is, relabelling the vertices of the graph.

To prove that the existence of a bridge is a graph invariant formally, we should:

- Let $G=(V,E)$ be an arbitrary graph with a bridge $ij \in E$.  Let $\varphi$ denote a bijection with domain $V$.  Show that $\varphi(i)\varphi(j)$ is a bridge in $\varphi(G)$.
- Repeat the above for when $ij$ is a non-bridge.

*Note*: this proves the stronger (but unsurprising) result that the number of bridges is preserved under isomorphism.